# How to convert a string with date and time to DateTime data type?

Tags: c#, string, datetime

A client is sending a string containing a date in format `YYYYMMDDHHmmSS` (e.g. `201004224432`).  There are no separators like `/` or `-`.

How can I easily convert this to a DateTime object? `Convert.ToDateTime()` does not work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx):

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(
                       "201004224432", 
                       "yyyyMMddHHmmss",
                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Note the tweaks to your format string to work appropriately.

Comment: @Michael: Thanks!  Suggestions won't seem to work unless you fix all of their problems ;)

Answer (score 9):

You want [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx), which can take in a formatting string like yours and use it to parse the input string.

Answer (score 0):

use this code sample

> using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using
>   System.ComponentModel; using System.Data; using System.Drawing; using
>   System.Text; using System.Windows.Forms;
>
> namespace DateTimeConvert {
>       public partial class Form1 : Form
>       {
>           public Form1()
>           {
>               InitializeComponent();
>           }
>
> ```
>     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>       label1.Text= ConvDate_as_str(textBox1.Text);
>     }
>
>     public string ConvDate_as_str(string dateFormat)
>     {
>         try
>         {
>             char[] ch = dateFormat.ToCharArray();
>             string[] sps = dateFormat.Split(' ');
>             string[] spd = sps[0].Split('.');
>             dateFormat = spd[0] + ":" + spd[1]+" "+sps[1];
>             DateTime dt = new DateTime();
>             dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dateFormat);
>             return dt.Hour.ToString("00") + dt.Minute.ToString("00");
>         }
>         catch (Exception ex)
>         {
>             return "Enter Correct Format like <5.12 pm>";
>         }
>
>     }
>
>
>     private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>        label2.Text = ConvDate_as_date(textBox2.Text);
>     }
>
>     public string ConvDate_as_date(string stringFormat)
>     {
>         try
>         {
>             string hour = stringFormat.Substring(0, 2);
>             string min = stringFormat.Substring(2, 2);
>             DateTime dt = new DateTime();
>             dt = Convert.ToDateTime(hour+":"+min);
>             return String.Format("{0:t}", dt); ;
>         }
>         catch (Exception ex)
>         {
>             return "Please Enter Correct format like <0559>";
>         }
>     }
> } }
> ```

Comment: Why should the OP use this code sample? Explain your solutions!